# Initializing utf8 encoded string c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, utf-8

I have a problem initializing utf-8 encoded string. I am using Visual Studio 2013.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::string_literals; // enables s-suffix for std::string         literals

int main()
{

string S1 = u8"hello"; // std::string

}

Error   1   error C2039: 'string_literals' : is not a member of 'std'                   c:\users\veroonika\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\string literals test u8 string\string literals test u8 string\source.cpp   5   1   string literals test u8 string
Error   2   error C2871: 'string_literals' : a namespace with this name does not exist  c:\users\veroonika\documents\visual studio 2013\projects\string literals test u8 string\string literals test u8 string\source.cpp   5   1   string literals test u8 string
```

Why does compiler not recognize the namespace?

Comment: VS2013 doesn't support user-defined literals, you need VS2015. See the table [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx#featurelist)

Comment: What compilers on windows platform support most c++11, 14 , 17 features?

Comment: @fredric: Embarcadero RADStudio: [C++11 Features Supported by RAD Studio Clang-based C++ Compilers](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C++11_Features_Supported_by_RAD_Studio_Clang-based_C++_Compilers) and [C++11 Language Features Compliance Status](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/C++11_Language_Features_Compliance_Status).

Answer (score 3):

Are you sure you can use `std::string_literals` with Visual Studio 2013? According to [this feature list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) it isn't available.